# Adding condition to existing formula to not trigger formula if another cell is blank

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I'm new to adding formulas etc. in Google Sheets, and I'm currently trying to set up a library borrowing/returns spreadsheet.

I have three columns formatted to dates: 'G' (date borrowed), 'H' (date due) and 'I' (date returned).

In 'H' I have the following formula to count 20 days from the date in column 'G', whilst also not firing if 'G' is blank:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(ISBLANK(G6),"",DATEVALUE(G6)+20))
```

This works great.

I also have conditional format to highlight 'H' in red if the date becomes overdue, which is:

> Value is less than
>   =TODAY()

This does the job initially, except that I need the format which makes 'H' highlight red NOT to fire if there is a return date entered in column 'I' (otherwise every entry will eventually turn red, and that's not really helpful for what I'm doing!).

I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

I feel it should be simple to add an `ISBLANK` type command into the `=TODAY()` format, but I'm clearly missing something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: [Here's a link to the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eLMke9ILmlVSv1etCBlVBavhuc6DKT2QNcush-sz7Vg/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a custom formula you are after:

**`=IF(I5="",COUNTIF(H5,"<"&TODAY()),)`**

[image]